# UISwipeGestureRecognizer over UIButtons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I want swipes to be detected on the lower half of the screen. That part of the screen can have `UIButtons` as well. I want the swipes to take priority over the buttons (that is, if you swipe over the buttons, the buttons are ignored). But I want the buttons to work if you just tap on them.

I tried placing a transparent view over the buttons with the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` attached, but obviously that makes the the buttons not to work as it swallows all touches including taps.

I also tried placing the transparent view behind the buttons, but then the `UIButton` event handling interferes with the swipe when you swipe over the button.

What's the best way to get this working?

---

I can think of a solution where the buttons would just be `UIImageViews` with attached `UITapGestureRecognizers` so you can then prioritize between the tap recognizers and the swipe recognizers.

But I'd like to keep the buttons as `UIButtons` to take advantage of the highlighted stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try adding the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the superview of the `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve same issue.

you just subclass UIButton and override 'touches~' method.

and then connect your customButton to it's parentView via some delegate.